# Strings as objects kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Actually this is an easy task, but I don't know why I still get errors like this

> Failed test #4 of 8. Wrong answer

this is my code

```
fun main() {
val input = readLine()!!

if (input.isEmpty()){
    println(input)
} else if (input.first().equals('i')) {
    println(input.drop(1).toInt() + 1)
} else if (input.first().equals('s')) {
    println(input.drop(1).reversed())
}}
```

I downloaded the failed test and the result is

> ft

you can check the task in this [link](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/6782)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct answer

```
fun main() {
    val input = readLine()!!
    // write code here
    if (input.isEmpty()){
        println(input)
    } else if (input.first().equals('i')) {
        println(input.drop(1).toInt() + 1)
    } else if (input.first().equals('s')) {
        println(input.drop(1).reversed())
    } else {
        println(input)
    }
}
```